# Why not editable cell has a cursor?

Tags: grid, cursor, devexpress

I have a grid, I have set:

```
this.gridColAlias1.AppearanceHeader.Options.UseTextOptions = true;
this.gridColAlias1.AppearanceHeader.TextOptions.HAlignment =DevExpress.Utils.HorzAlignment.Near;
this.gridColAlias1.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = false;
```

I see the column on my grid is not editable, but anyway I see a cursor on the cell of that column and hence it pretends editable. Why this happens and how could I get rid of the cursor?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean when you talk about the cursor? There is no cursor (caret) within the cell when the [OptionsColumn.AllowEdit](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsOptionsColumn_AllowEdittopic) property is set to false. Maybe you mean a focus rectangle?
To avoid the focus rectangle to be drawn on the particular column cell, you can make this column unfocusable via the [OptionsColumn.AllowFocus](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridColumnsOptionsColumn_AllowFocustopic) property.

Comment: About cursor, I mean the one you can use to select the words in the cell.

Comment: I'm afraid that I can't replicate the problem on my side - there is no cursor within the non-editable cells and I can't select any content of these cells. It can appears only when you set the OptionsColumn.Readonly property to true, but don't set the OptionsColumn.AllowEdit property to false.
Please check these properties or give me full details on your gridview settings.